# JAVA - BFS to a limited friendship level in a graph

Tags: java, algorithm, graph, breadth-first-search

I am working on an undirected graph implementation for a simple social network. Users are represented using their IDs (Integers), and I need to find different levels of friendship.
I used the Adjacency List approach as my graph is very sparse. I used a hashmap to hold users and their friends:

```
Map<Integer, Set<Integer>> graph;
```

Using this implementation, I am able to find the first and second levels of friendship. However, I wrote a method that uses BFS to find if two users are fourth-level friends.

For example, if the graph contains following edges:
1-2
2-3
3-4
4-5
Then 1 and 5 are fourth-level friends, and my method should return true when 1 and 5 are passed to it as parameters.

**The problem** is that my method always returns false when it is called in the main, even if the method itself is tested and is correct! Here is the method, and again it is correct and working.

```
public boolean checkLevelBFS(Integer source, Integer dest) {
    Queue<Integer> toVisitQueue = new LinkedList<>(graph.get(source));
    Set<Integer> visited = new HashSet<>();
    visited.add(source);
    Integer inreaser = new Integer(-1); // indicator for level increase
    toVisitQueue.add(inreaser);
    int level = 1; // because we already passed the source and started from its children nodes
    while (level <= 4 && !toVisitQueue.isEmpty()) {
        Integer currentNode = toVisitQueue.remove();
        if (currentNode.equals(dest)) {
            return true;
        }
        if (visited.contains(currentNode)) {
            continue;
        }
        if (currentNode.equals(inreaser)) {
            level++;
            toVisitQueue.add(inreaser);
            continue;
        }
        visited.add(currentNode);
        for (Integer child : graph.get(currentNode)) {
            if (!visited.contains(child)){
                toVisitQueue.add(child);
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

The part that makes the code return false is below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Basics x = new Basics();
    x.graph = new HashMap<>();

    Set<Integer> s = new HashSet<>();

    s.add(2);
    x.graph.put(1, s);

    s = new HashSet<>();
    s.add(1);
    s.add(3);
    x.graph.put(2, s);

    s = new HashSet<>();
    s.add(2);
    s.add(4);
    x.graph.put(3, s);

    s = new HashSet<>();
    s.add(3);
    s.add(5);
    x.graph.put(4, s);

    s = new HashSet<>();
    s.add(4);
    s.add(6);
    x.graph.put(5, s);

    s = new HashSet<>();
    s.add(5);
    x.graph.put(6, s);

    if (!x.initialCheck(1, 5)) {
        System.out.println("A new user is involved");
    } else {
        if (x.levelOneFriends(1, 5)) {
            System.out.println("friends");
        } else {
            System.out.println("not friends");
            if (x.levelTwoFriends(1, 5)) {
                System.out.println("friends level 2");
            } else {
                System.out.println("not friends of level 2");
                if (x.checkLevelBFS(1, 5)) {
                    System.out.println("YES - friends of level 4");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("NO - not friends of level 4");
                }
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(x.checkLevelBFS(1, 2));
    System.out.println(x.checkLevelBFS(1, 3));
    System.out.println(x.checkLevelBFS(1, 4));
    System.out.println(x.checkLevelBFS(1, 5));
    System.out.println(x.checkLevelBFS(1, 6));
}
```

Output:

```
not friends
not friends of level 2
NO - not friends of level 4
false
false
false
false
false
```

The first two lines are correct outputs, the third is not correct as 1 and 5 are frieds of level 4, and should print YES -
The following 'false' outputs are weird too!

'initialCheck' checks if any of the two users is not already in the graph.
'levelOneFriends' checks if the two objects are direct friends.
'levelTwoFriends' checks if the two objects are in the relation Friend of Friend.

Any help?

Thanks!

Comment: What's `Graph#get(Integer)` ? (Need to know what it does, but I am going to guess you don't add `source` to the original queue, and that's why it fails.

Comment: @amit - It is to get all friends of that node from the hashmap

Comment: @aim - The source is already processed at the first step, and it is added to the 'visited' set. I also tried to start from the source and level = 0. Didn't work too

Comment: @amit See that `Map<Integer, Set<Integer>> graph; ` line in the Q?

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi Now I do, thanks.

Comment: Based on my tests, the bug may be in the calling code. At least for some smoke test cases, the method seems to work.

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi I edited the post. Now I know where the bug happens, but I don't know why!

Comment: @Yano Still **Works4Me** see updated answer.

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi Something is happening when I call the levelTwoFriends() method:

Comment: public boolean levelTwoFriends(Integer user1, Integer user2) {
  Collection<Integer> c =  graph.get(user1);
  c.retainAll(graph.get(user2));
  return !c.isEmpty();
 }

Comment: I GOT IT!!! retainAll(Collection<?> c1) removes items from c1 and from the source (in the graph) of the object c

Comment: @Yano "I GOT IT!!!" Oh, the wonders of debugging, will they ever cease? :P See my updated answer for a concise rewrite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Edited after OP's comment showing `levelTwoFriends`]

```
public boolean levelTwoFriends(Integer user1, Integer user2) { 
  Collection<Integer> c = graph.get(user1);
  // c.retainAll(graph.get(user2)); 
  // return !c.isEmpty(); 

  // true only if a non-void intersection
  return false==Collections.disjoint(c, graph.get(user2));
}
```

or, as a one-liner

```
public boolean levelTwoFriends(Integer user1, Integer user2) { 
  return false==Collections.disjoint( graph.get(user1), graph.get(user2) );
}
```

---

[Edited after update with `x.initialCheck`]

Your bug then must be in the `x.initialCheck` and the other stuff that you are doing before actually getting into `x.checkLevelBFS`. Verify the `x.initialCheck` and `x.levelOneFriends` against modification in the internal representation of you adjacency list (there *must* be one there - run the in debugger and keep an eye on modification of the content). Why I say this? Because the below code works as intended:

```
  static public void main(String[] args) {
    ExampleTest x=new ExampleTest(); // in your case, it's Basics

    x.graph=new HashMap<>();
    x.graph.put(1, new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(2)));
    x.graph.put(2, new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(1,3)));
    x.graph.put(3, new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(2,4)));
    x.graph.put(4, new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(3,5)));
    x.graph.put(5, new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(4,6)));
    x.graph.put(6, new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(5)));
    System.out.println(x.checkLevelBFS(1, 2)); // true
    System.out.println(x.checkLevelBFS(1, 3)); // true
    System.out.println(x.checkLevelBFS(1, 4)); // true
    System.out.println(x.checkLevelBFS(1, 5)); // true
    System.out.println(x.checkLevelBFS(1, 6)); // false
  }
```

---

> "The problem is that my method always returns false!"

But it doesn't! Your bug may be in some other place!!!

I'll be marking this as **Works for me** and closing the bug.

My code used for driving the tests.

```
class ExampleTest {
  Map<Integer, Set<Integer>> graph;  

  static public void main(String[] args) {
    ExampleTest x=new ExampleTest();
    x.graph=new HashMap<>();
    x.graph.put(1, new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(2)));
    x.graph.put(2, new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(3)));
    x.graph.put(3, new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(4)));
    x.graph.put(4, new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(5)));
    x.graph.put(5, new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(6)));
    System.out.println(x.checkLevelBFS(1, 2)); // true
    System.out.println(x.checkLevelBFS(1, 3)); // true
    System.out.println(x.checkLevelBFS(1, 4)); // true
    System.out.println(x.checkLevelBFS(1, 5)); // true
    System.out.println(x.checkLevelBFS(1, 6)); // false
  }

  // verbatim copy of your method here
  public boolean checkLevelBFS(Integer source, Integer dest) {
    Queue<Integer> toVisitQueue = new LinkedList<>(graph.get(source));
    Set<Integer> visited = new HashSet<>();
    visited.add(source);
    Integer inreaser = new Integer(-1); // indicator for level increase
    toVisitQueue.add(inreaser);
    int level = 1; // because we already passed the source and started from its children nodes
    while (level <= 4 && !toVisitQueue.isEmpty()) {
      Integer currentNode = toVisitQueue.remove();
      if (currentNode.equals(dest)) {
        return true;
      }
      if (visited.contains(currentNode)) {
        continue;
      }
      if (currentNode.equals(inreaser)) {
        level++;
        toVisitQueue.add(inreaser);
        continue;
      }
      visited.add(currentNode);
      for (Integer child : graph.get(currentNode)) {
        if (!visited.contains(child)){
          toVisitQueue.add(child);
        }
      }
    }
    return false;
  }

}
```

Comment: Yea that works! I am trying to find another spot. My full code is very lengthy and it includes files. Is it fine if I post the whole thing?

Comment: @Yano "Is it fine if I post the whole thing?" No, this is frown upon on SO. A [MCVE] is expected. The advantage of such an example: trying to get out the non-essential, you usually find the bug yourself.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's why I asked! Anyway I did simplify my code and will post the part that is causing the bug in a moment

Comment: @Yano "Thanks a lot." Also usual on SO: thanks are best expressed by upvoting and/or accepting a helpful answer. Otherwise: your welcome.

Comment: I did. and I just posted a simplified main method where the method returns false. You may take a look.

Comment: could you try my main? you may use your "put" style